# A chart of the number of UN members by year

Tags: united-nations

Is there a chart somewhere that would show the number of UN member states by year?

Comment: If you ultimately answered the question yourself, please add that information as an 'answer'. Embedding that information into the question does not allow others to vet the answer, vote, comments, etc. Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino it is based on answer by Yannis. Why downvote?

Comment: @Anixx Please do not undo this edit.  Questions are where you ask questions.  Answers are where you get answers.  I see you perferred a different visualization, but as it was really based on Yannis' source, it really belonged there.  If you really must not put it with the answer, then I suggest you post a second answer and put it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UN has a list of [growth in membership by year](https://www.un.org/en/members/growth.shtml) on their website. Creating a chart from that data is relatively easy:

[image]

If you want to see it cumulatively, here it is.

[image]